# VirtualHost Server Not Found

Tags: apache-2.2, php, web-server, virtualhost, mac

After modifying the httpd.conf to include my virtual host configuration:  `Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`, I added the following to my virtual host configuration file:

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:8085

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
#<VirtualHost *:80>
#    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
#    DocumentRoot "/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
#    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
#    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
#    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
#    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
#</VirtualHost>

#<VirtualHost *:80>
#    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
#    DocumentRoot "/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
#    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
#    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
#    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
#</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8085>
    ServerName 127.0.0.1:8085
    DocumentRoot "/Users/path/to/root/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I restarted my apache server, and it says that 127.0.0.1 cannot be found. I checked everything that I did is correct, but I could not figure what the problem is.

- The path to the directory that I want to serve exist.
- `sudo apachectl -S` returns

>

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:8085                 is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 127.0.0.1 (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:44)
         port 8085 namevhost 127.0.0.1 (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:44)
Syntax OK
```

<

Can someone point to me how I can get my virtual host running?

[EDIT]

Error Log (`/var/log/apache2/error_log`):

```
[Sat Jul 19 19:12:38 2014] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Sat Jul 19 19:12:38 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Jul 19 19:12:38 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Sat Jul 19 19:12:38 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is not a name, it's an IP address.

Comment: Are you trying to access `http://127.0.0.1`, or `http://127.0.0.1:8085`?  What's giving you the "cannot be found" error, and what's the exact error message?

Comment: Sorry, I meant 127.0.0.1:8085. "Cannot be found" as if the server does not exist. I put a screenshot up later.

Comment: Can you provide Error log of apache

Comment: [Sat Jul 19 19:12:38 2014] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Sat Jul 19 19:12:38 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Jul 19 19:12:38 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Sat Jul 19 19:12:38 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y configured -- resuming normal operations

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think what you want is an IP-based virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8085>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/path/to/root/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Can you explain more what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have multiple projects that I want to test locally before deploying them remotely. So, I want to setup a virtual host that will serve these projects locally for testing purpose instead of testing them remotely, and I'm having some trouble with setting a virtual host that I can test my changes.

Comment: I still can't assess 127.0.0.1:8085 with the following change. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: check with `lsof -i :8085` if the adress is REALLY listening to your requests :-)